# Is implementing IComparable<T> sufficient for sorting or do I need to also implement IComparer?

Tags: c#, .net, icomparable, icomparer

Is it sufficient to Implement `IComparable<T>` for an object of my definition that I want to have in a list to be sorted?

For e.g
I have this class definition

```
public sealed class StreamInfo : ICloneable, IExtensibleDataObject, IEquatable<StreamInfo>, IComparable<StreamInfo>
```

with 4 properties (1 string, 1 enum, and 2 ulong). I use these 4 properties to implement CompareTo function

```
public int CompareTo(StreamInfo other)
{
// details of implementation irrelevant to question
}
```

Somewhere else in the codebase, I maintain a list of `StreamInfo`.

`List<StreamInfo> StreamInfoObj;`

I would like to Sort the list using the [Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-list-1-sort) call:

Is the default Comparer, the one I implemented in the `StreamInfo` class by means of `CompareTo` above?
Or do I still need to implement a class that inherits from IComparer and pass that to the Sort method? Just like the example below?
Or is that unnecessary?

For example:

```
public sealed class OrderStreamsInfoAscending : IComparer<StreamInfo>
    {
        public int Compare(StreamInfo x, StreamInfo y)
        {
            if (x == null && y == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if (x == null)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if ( y == null)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            var result = x.CompareTo(y);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Thank you

[image]

Comment: I might have answered my own question by looking at the Exception documentation for the ```Sort``` method. Indicating an exception will be thrown if it cannot find implementation of IComparable for type T.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [`Sort()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-list-1-sort) method (without parameters), List class will use the default comparer, and if your class implements `IComparable<T>`, the List class will use that implementation.

If you use [`Sort(IComparer<T>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-list-1-sort(system-collections-generic-icomparer((-0)))) – then the List class will use the `IComparer<T>` implementation, and ignore `IComparable<T>` implementation (if your class implements it).